# Textbox binding default value for empty text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I want a `TextBox` in `Listview` DataTemplate, which is bound to an int or double property takes `0` or `0.0` automatically  when it is made empty i.e. when the whole text of the `TextBox` is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You could put in [value converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which convert empty strings to 0/0.0 in `ConvertBack`. After the binding propagates back to the source the binding engine usually fetches the value again so you should end up with that as the `Text`.